# Actualizar objeto en Firebase cuando la aplicación está desplegada

Tags: java, android, firebase, object

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android utilizando Firebase. 
La manera en la que guardo en Firebase, es grabando un objeto y luego obteniendolo de la siguiente manera:

```
Object c = postSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);
```

Pero mi pregunta es, si una vez lanzada la aplicación, quiero actualizar un objeto, porque he añadido cosas en la aplicación que lo requiere, los usuarios que no se hayan actualizado la aplicación, no tendrán el objeto actualizado y al llamar a la Firebase dará un error.

¿Cómo se puede controlar esto?

Muchas gracias,
Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes crear un dialogo donde le des aviso a usuario que existe una nueva versión y que sin ella, la app no sera funcional al 100% ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen dia, tan facil como poner un try catch, con el try catch en la seccion donde la app llama a ese objeto podras hacer que si esta lo traiga y sino te tire un catch , que dentro de ese error podrias poner un alertdialog que diga (necesitas actualizar la app)

por ejemplo

```
 try {

Object c = postSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debes actualizar la app para obtener/subir este archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Recuerda que lo que hace el try catch es agarrar un bloque de codigo que quieras probar y primero intenta y ve si puede lograr hacer lo que dices, pero si no sucede , en vez de hacer que la app haga un crash va a tirar un error y no mas, en ese error puedes decirle al usuario que actualize la app

Espero mi respuesta te sirva, saludos

pd: en mi app tengo implementado un control de version bastante sencillo, lo que debes hacer es crear un valor en el databse de firebase con la version de tu app, luego vas a tu app y obtienes ese valor, luego obtienes el valor de tu propia app, entonces haces un if preguntando si los valores de la version actual y la version de firebase difieren, si es que difieren llamas a un alertdialog que dice que necesita actualizar la app (generalmente se hace en el splashactivity o en el MainActivity ) sino, si tu version es igual a la de firebase, continuas usando la app

Comment: Gran respuesta! 

Voy a añadir un control de versiones. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena recomendación sería usar [Remote Config de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) para definir una variable como "versión del objeto". Utilizando remote config podrías definir un atributo que se vaya segmentando por versión de la app, plataforma, tipo de usuario, etc y así poder cambiar la lógica de tu app en base a esa version.